# Wing IDE 101 says some values are invalid

Tags: python, wing-ide

In WingIDE 101:

When I go to Source- Current File Properties - Debug - Show this dialog before each run - Apply: I get the error:

> Some values are invalid:
>
> - Python executable 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\' is not a file
> - Initial directory '' does not exist
>
> Please correct the values and try again.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the radio button selection for Initial Directory is set to Use Default or enter a valid initial directory there if leaving it set to Custom.  Similarly, under the Environment tab you need to correct the radio button setting for Python Executable or enter a valid path to a python.exe.